# How do I convert ticks to minutes?

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

I have a ticks value of 28000000000 which should be 480 minutes but how can I be sure? How do I convert a ticks value to minutes?

Answer (score 157):

```
TimeSpan.FromTicks(28000000000).TotalMinutes;
```

Answer (score 128):

> A single tick represents one hundred nanoseconds or one ten-millionth of a second. FROM MSDN.

So 28 000 000 000  * 1/10 000 000 = 2 800 sec.
2 800 sec /60 = 46.6666min

Or you can do it programmaticly with TimeSpan:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromTicks(28000000000);
        double minutesFromTs = ts.TotalMinutes;
        Console.WriteLine(minutesFromTs);
        Console.Read();
    }
```

Both give me 46 min and not 480 min...

Comment: lol who down voted me? Both mathematical and coded one really give me 46 min and not this 480 min.

Comment: Maybe someone down voted you for rounding 46.6666 to 46? ;-) No, actually, I had down voted you by mistake, I have removed the down vote now. Sorry!

Comment: Actually, to be clear, I have not only removed the down vote. I have up voted your comprehensive answer. Sir.

Comment: Voted up for including the math version as well as the TimeSpan version.

Answer (score 35):

You can do this way:

```
TimeSpan duration = new TimeSpan(tickCount)
double minutes = duration.TotalMinutes;
```

Comment: lol - you answered one minute earlier than Jon Skeet, but his answer has more votes!?

Answer (score 26):

The clearest way in my view is to use [TimeSpan.FromTicks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromticks.aspx) and then convert that to minutes:

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromTicks(ticks);
double minutes = ts.TotalMinutes;
```

Answer (score 11):

there are 600 million ticks per minute.
[ticksperminute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.ticksperminute)

Comment: ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMinute

Answer (score 4):

TimeSpan.FromTicks( 28000000000 ).TotalMinutes;

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime mydate = new Date(2012,3,2,5,2,0);
int minute = mydate/600000000;
```

will return minutes of from given date (mydate) to current time.hope this help.cheers