# Performing a Sum() with LINQ query on database

Tags: c#, sql, database, linq, select

I am querying my database which has the following

Table: TimeEntries

- field1: ProjectName
- field2: Phase
- field3: TimeWorked

What I am trying to do is group by ProjectName and Phase and sum() the TimeWorked for each.

So if I had this in the table for:
ProjectName, Phase,  Timeworked

1. Project1---     1 ---    3.5
2. Project1 ---    1   ---   2
3. Project2  ---   1   ---   1

My query would return:

1. Project1---1---5.5
2. Project2---1---1

currently this is what I have:

```
var query3 = (from timeEntry in context.TimeEntries
   select new
      {
          ProjectName = timeEntry.ProjectName,
          Phase = timeEntry.Phase,
          LoggedHours = context.TimeEntries.Sum(x => x.TimeWorked)
      });
```

Not sure if I am even on the right track, could someone help me out?

Here is a picture of the database tables with their data types:
[TimeEntry Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fmzp3.png),
[Project Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgzH1.png)

Comment: See the first answer on [LINQ GroupBy Sum and Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522645/linq-groupby-sum-and-count) and adapt to your needs

Comment: This looks oddly similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48892874/perform-calculations-on-a-set-using-only-linq) asked a few minutes ago. There's enough difference that I could be imagining it. But both involve adding the total time worked for a set of entries, and both specify using LINQ.

Comment: The answers here may also help with the groupby part.  I see you are attempting to group by 2 fields. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847066/group-by-multiple-columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
    var result=context.TimeEntries.GroupBy(m=>new {m.Name,m.Phase})
.Select(m=>new {
Name=m.Key.Name,
Phase=m.Key.Phase,
TimeWorked=m.Sum(o=>o.TimeWorked)

});
```

Comment: Perfect! thank you so much. could you please explain how you reached this conclusion. I am trying to learn LINQ still.